# MySQL Select AVG using several WHERE clauses

Tags: php, mysql, count, sum, average

I have a search engine for an online shop, i want to give the user the chance to filter the products by rating, until now my query looks like this:

```
SELECT products.*,prices.price,AVG(ratings_products.rating)
FROM products,prices,ratings_products
WHERE products.title REGEXP 'lg' AND products.active = 'yes'
AND prices.price >= '10' AND prices.price <= '298650'
AND products.cod_product = prices.id_product
AND ratings_products.ratings >= '40' AND ratings_products.ratings <= 59
AND ratings_products.id_product = products.cod_product
AND products.id_category = '59' LIMIT 0,1
```

The idea is to filter by price, specific filters and rating, all works except the ratings. I have the table ratings_products with the following structure:

```
id | id_product | id_user | title | comment | date | rating
1  |      18    |    65   |awesome| some    |12344 | 85
2  |      18    |    84   |cool   | great   |12345 | 20
```

Now i need to AVG to return the average between 85 and 20, but the query is returning NULL, if i delete the `ratings_products.rating <= 59` it gives me the result but is not calculating the average.

Appreciate any help

Thanks

Comment: Why do you have single quotes around all integers except the one that's giving you trouble? You shouldn't need any quotes around integers.

Comment: Because not always will be an integer, there's not showing the quotes but it also has it.

Comment: So does putting quotes around rating change anything?

Comment: No, the thing is that due to AVG function the query is returning all values null, if i remove the second ratings_products.ratings, the query returns the other values but the one specified as AVG is returned as the value of the row, not the average.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
AND ratings_products.ratings >= '40' AND ratings_products.ratings <= 59
```

This means you want the values between 40 and 59. You display 20 and 85 in your example, neither is in the range you query for so that result is `NULL`

Removing the `AND ratings_products.ratings <= 59` part leaves a query for ratings higher than 40, that is 85, on its own, nothing to average.

Am I missing something or are you querying for the wrong values?

Comment: Actually you helped me out, you were right, i don't have to look for those values, only calculate the average, so for the query i delete "AND ratings_products.ratings >= '40' AND ratings_products.ratings <= 59" and leaves only "AND ratings_products.id_product = products.cod_product"